# Is there any simple way to install Magento 2.4.1?

Tags: magento2.4.1, ubuntu

Whenever I am running this command to install Magento 2.4.1

```
php bin/magento setup:install 
    --base-url="http://192.168.1.128/magento"
    --db-host="localhost"
    --db-name="magento2"
    --db-user="root"
    --db-password="Rudra@665"
    --admin-firstname="admin"
    --admin-lastname="sharma"
    --admin-email="abhpri13@gmail.com"
    --admin-user="admin"
    --admin-password="admin@123"
    --use-rewrites="1"
    --backend-frontname="admin"
```

This is showing the error in the Ubuntu command line

> There are no commands defined in the "setup" namespace.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please provide more details about the conditions in which you executed this command:

1. Which were your previous steps and commands you executed prior to the setup:install command?
2. Have you checked that you have the correct permissions in the folder you are running this command?
3. Are you executing this command on a clean 2.4.1 downloaded code from the Magento metapackage? or is there anything custom in there also?

Comment: it worked now ......thanks

Comment: you're welcome, but you did all the work actually :) but what was the problem? maybe it will be useful for others in the future.

Comment: it was not giving the permissions correctly.

Comment: understood. glad you sorted it out.